# Graphviz: How to create overlapping subnode on another?

Tags: networking, graphviz, diagram, venn-diagram

I want to create sub node like above which overlap the another half inline and out.
[image]

```
digraph G {
node [fontsize=8  margin=".1,.01" width=.5 height=.5 shape=box]
edge [fontsize=8]
rankdir=LR;
ranksep = .25;
nodesep= .5;
{
    subgraph cluster0 {
        label = "VMWare";
        {
            subgraph cluster3{
                style = dashed;
                color=red;
                label = "ESX";
                VM1 
                [
                    shape = rectangle
                    label = "Virtual Machine 1"
                ]
                VPN_NIC [shape = rectangle label="Physical NIC\nPromiscuous mode ON" style=rounded]
                VM1 -> VPN_NIC [style=dotted];
            }
        }
        edge [dir=none]
        INT_NET [label = "Internal Network"];
        VPN_NIC -> INT_NET;
    }
}
```

}

[image]

I would like to make the component named Physical NIC as overlapped on ESXi border line.
Perhaps this kind of requirement would come when showing network diagram - especially bridges connecting with internal as well as outer network.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an example of some code you've written to try and create this?

Comment: Thanks @thesecretmaster updated my code, but as of now, either I could place the node inside the cluster or outside of the cluster.

Comment: Sadly I don't know much about graphviz, I was just trying to make it easier for someone who does know to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can come close with HTML label, you will however have to merge the overlapping nodes in to one node e.g.:

```
digraph name {
rankdir=LR

X[shape=none margin=0 label=<
<table cellspacing="0" cellborder="1" border="0">
<tr><td sides="LT"></td><td sides="TR"></td><td sides="L"></td></tr>
<tr><td sides="L">Some text</td><td colspan="2" style="rounded" port="a">Line 1<br/>Line 2</td></tr>
<tr><td sides="LB"></td><td sides="BR"></td><td sides="L"></td></tr>
</table>
>]

X:a:e->Y
}
```

Rendered on viz-js.com:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jens, with your solution it's possible to put it on node border. However, as per the question I wanted to put it on border of two subgraphs.

Comment: @vkumbhar94 I don't think you can put a node on the border of a subgraph. Also it seems like the question header is in accurate